# How to place an order on a Serum testnet market using Solana?

Tags: solana

I'm trying to place an order on a Serum testnet market (SOL/USDT) in my case. I know I'm probably doing a couple of things wrong but I can't spot them. Here's my code:

```
let connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet")),
    wallet = web3.Keypair.generate();
  console.log('Airdropping some SOL');
  let airdropSignature = await connection.requestAirdrop(
    wallet.publicKey,
    web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL,
  );

  await connection.confirmTransaction(airdropSignature);
  let myMint = new web3.PublicKey("So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112"),
    myToken = new splToken.Token(
        connection,
        myMint,
        splToken.TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        wallet
    );
  // Create associated token accounts for my token if they don't exist yet
  var ownerTokenAccount = await myToken.getOrCreateAssociatedAccountInfo(wallet.publicKey);

  console.log('Placing order...');
  let market = await handlers.fetchMarketData(new web3.PublicKey('HWHvQhFmJB3NUcu1aihKmrKegfVxBEHzwVX6yZCKEsi1')), //SOL/USDT
    owner = ownerTokenAccount,
    payer = owner,
    res = await market.placeOrder(connection, { //TODO: Add error handling
      owner,
      payer,
      side: 'sell',
      price: 1,
      size: 1.0,
      orderType: 'limit',
    })
```

Comment: Hi, can I ask what library are you using for serum interacting?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `HWHvQhFmJB3NUcu1aihKmrKegfVxBEHzwVX6yZCKEsi1` on testnet is just a random system account, so there's no serum market initialized on it.

- Mainnet account / Serum market: https://explorer.solana.com/address/HWHvQhFmJB3NUcu1aihKmrKegfVxBEHzwVX6yZCKEsi1
- Testnet account / Unused system account: https://explorer.solana.com/address/HWHvQhFmJB3NUcu1aihKmrKegfVxBEHzwVX6yZCKEsi1?cluster=testnet

I thought some Serum markets ran on devnet, but now I can't find any unfortunately.  You may have to set this all up yourself by deploying the Serum program and populating the order book.  Here are some resources to help with that:

- Serum source code so you can build / deploy the program: https://github.com/project-serum/serum-dex/tree/master/dex
- How to launch a market: https://docs.projectserum.com/serum-ecosystem/build-on-serum/add-a-market-on-serum-serum-academy
- Connect to a local network and launch a market: https://openserum.ch/dex/
- Whenever you're ready, you can move it all to testnet and get USDC using the faucet: https://www.usdcfaucet.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I figure it should be an easier way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's the only option when the markets and program don't exist.  Check around, I really think that some Serum markets exist on devnet, but I can't remember where they're deployed to, or who deployed them.  You can try asking on the Serum / Anchor Discord: https://discord.gg/y63hX4YA